# What is the difference between Cost and Price?

Tags: shipping

I'm currently reviewing code that edit a shipping method and there's

```
$method->setCost([int]);
$method->setPrice([int]);
```

What is the difference between those two? When should they be different or the same?

Thanks

Comment: I think I found it while asking, cost is what the merchant pays and price is what the customer pays.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of these words ;-) Feel free to add it as an answer and accept your own answer as soon as the site allows it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cost is what the merchant pays.

The price is what the customer pays.